# How do you run a server-side script without it being sent to the browser at all?

Tags: javascript, html

I understand that the title is a little confusing, but essentially I want to make my website run a php file on the server side that uses arguments from the html e.g

```
document.getElementById("example").value;
```

So I'd like to run it on the server but not have it linked to the html file. Is this possible?

Comment: You'll probably have to set up your server to not kill scripts when the connection gets closed. Then do a call from your client-side JavaScript to your server-side script

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create PHP scripts on server side and reach them with [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) (tutorial [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp)) or [AJAX with Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/) for example.
PHP scripts you need, don't have to generate any HTML code : they just would process data.
In your JS, you get your values from the page, then you send your data to the server.